How did the word FLUKE come to be associated with luck or chance?
How did the word FLUKE come to be associated with luck or chance?
What's currently available is speculation. Is that still "state of the art"?
See fluke (n.2) at Etymonline:

"lucky stroke, chance hit," 1857, also flook, said to be originally a lucky shot at billiards, of uncertain origin. Century Dictionary connects it with fluke (n.1) in reference to the whale's use of flukes to get along rapidly (to go a-fluking or some variant of it, "go very fast," is in Dana, Smyth, and other sailors' books of the era). OED (2nd ed. print) allows only that it is "Possibly of Eng. dialectal origin."

There's no explanation of how the established name for a flat fish (and the name of a worm that resembled a flat fish) came to be used in the context of a lucky shot in billiards and how it came to be used in the context of lucky or freak occurrences generally.

look it up first. https://www.etymonline.com/word/fluke

Wbat's currently available is speculation. Is that still "state of the art"?

The OED doesn't know. "Of unknown origin." So unless you want some dubious speculation, that's it.

@StuartF You'd be surprised--people doing research on this site can certainly turn up useful findings that the OED doesn't list.

According to https://idiomorigins.org/origin/fluke it was specific to billiards in the mid 19th century.

@Peter But there's no explanation of how the name for a flat fish (and  the name of a worm that resembled a flat fish) came to be used in that context.

@TimR Agreed there is no explanation. However it is not certain that the word derived from the name of the fish. It may have come from the flukes of an anchor or a whale, and these may alternatively have come from Low German flügel meaning "wing" (from etymologyonline.com).

The book Medical Meanings A Glossary of Word Origins (by William S. Haubrich) offers another etymological conjecture related to the sense "flatfish," suggesting it stems from the ease of catching flatfish or the idea of a lucky catch. Here is the entry for fluke from the book:

fluke in the descriptive sense of "flat" is related to the German flach and probably to the Latin plaga, "a flat surface." The name "fluke" is given to a flatfish (especially flounder), and parasitic flatworms are also commonly called "flukes," according to their habitat, be it blood, the intestine, the lung, or the liver (see trematode). The origin of "fluke" as an unexpected or accidental stroke of good luck is obscure. It seems to have come from the game of billiards where an accidentally successful shot, especially by a novice, was called a "fluke shot," perhaps because the common flatfish is easily caught by even an unskilled angler, or perhaps because a fish hooked by its fluke (tail) rather than its mouth is a lucky, if misdirected, catch.


"flat" was a slang-term for gullible person, someone easily taken (see Green's Dictionary of Slang). Green speculates that fluke, which also developed this slang meaning, did so as a result of some word-play with "flat". But I've seen 19th c. texts that talk about "fishing for flats" so it's likely flat was also a slang-term for these fish and there's no wordplay involved.  It could be that flat/fluke were easy to catch.  fluke later developed the meaning "amateur" and from there it's no big leap  to "lucky shot (by an unskilled player)" and from there to "a chance event".

@TimR Yes, it appears that the word flat was used for the fish in 19th century. OED has this citation from 1847, from the Dictionary of Archaic & Provincial Words vol. I by J. O. Halliwell,: "Flats, small white fresh-water fish, as roach, etc."

Since the status quo on this word's use in the context of Luck or Chance is based on speculation, I will also offer some speculation.
I was thinking that the parasite known as the "fluke" came to be associated with unexplained phenomena (because its lifecycle was a mystery) and that the semantic leap from unexplained phenomena  to  the results of Luck or Chance is not that big of a leap.

Our present information would lead us to conclude that it deposits ova, from which either within the maternal body or without it, oval shaped young proceed, which move about briskly in the fluid contained in the interior of the snail or in the surrounding water and bear no resemblance to their parent. In what way this progeny is transformed into a fluke or as we now know into a Cercaria is as yet an unexplained mystery but that this change can and does take place throughout only by the intervention of several generations may be assumed as beyond doubt.

The Monthly Review, Or, Literary Journal
Johannes Japetus, Sm Steenstrup (1845)

Speculation in answers confers an undeserved respectability that may start an urban myth. And I'd say this is wild, considering how different the domains are.

@EdwinAshworth Ironic that it was insisted I cite an "authority" that does nothing but speculate.

As for the domains being different, you reveal a post-scientific-era bias.  Before chance became associated with mathematical probabilities it was thought to be a cosmological force operating upon the sublunary realm and responsible for all manner of freak occurrences and disorder and unpredictability.  The fluke parasite worm was very well-known in agrarian England and that it became something associated with strange unexplainable phenomena  is not all that far-fetched. No more far-fetched, I'd say, than a billiards term achieving extra-billiards meaning.

“Liver fluke disease, or liver rot of sheep, has been recognized in Europe for centuries as causing enormous losses of sheep during wet seasons.”  Dr. Robert Dill, Reno, Nevada, undated. https://www.nal.usda.gov/exhibits/speccoll/exhibits/show/parasitic-diseases-with-econom/parasitic-diseases-with-econom/liver-flukes

'The basic sources of [The Online Etymological Dictionary] are Weekley's "An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English," Klein's "A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the English Language," "Oxford English Dictionary" (second edition), "Barnhart Dictionary of Etymology," Holthausen's "Etymologisches Wörterbuch der Englischen Sprache," and Kipfer and Chapman's "Dictionary of American Slang." ' Between them, these authorities will have carried out extensive research, even when the net result is 'of uncertain origin'.

I would be sceptical of this suggested derivation, if only because the word "fluke" in the context under discussion normally refers to a rare but happy event such as a fortunate billiard shot, while liver fluke disease produces unhappy events such as the loss of valuable sheep, and its occurrence is not rare in bad seasons.
